# Accessing a property in a Datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, visual-studio-2003

I am loading the output of a database query to a DataGrid.

```
myAdapter.Fill(ds,"AllInfo");
dataGridSearchOutput.DataSource = ds.Tables["AllInfo"].DefaultView;
```

It will fillup the data grid control with multiple records. Suppose the primary key of the data record is "ID".

Now I want to generate report. To do that I need to select an item and click a button "Generate Report" or double click a record. Then a report should be generated for that ID.

My question is How should I capture the ID of the record? In otherwords I need to read the selected value in datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value
```

Have a look at

- [DataGridView.CurrentRow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(VS.80).aspx)
- [get the selected row in datagridview](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread94061.html#)

EDIT:

Maybe then have a look at using [DataGrid.CurrentRowIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.currentrowindex.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Put it in the event handler for the click or double click...

```
DataView dv = (DataView)dataGridSearchOutput.DataSource;
DataRow selectedRow = dv.ToTable().Rows[dataGridSearchOutput.CurrentRowIndex];
long id = (long)selectedRow["ID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easy and bets approach is set GridView property DataKeyNames to ID and then you can have the ID easily using

```
int index = dataGridSearchOutput.SelectedIndex;
dataGridSearchOutput.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()
```

or you can convert it long as it is object.